Problem with SmartBrain App - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
I'm trying to solve an issue I've been having with my SmartBrain app. I completed the ZTM Web Developer course and completed the app but then had problems using it later on. I keep getting a "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)". Does anyone mind looking at my frontend and backend code? Thanks.
App.js:
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import ParticlesBg from 'particles-bg'
import Navigation from './components/Navigation/Navigation';
import Signin from './components/Signin/Signin';
import Register from './components/Register/Register';
import FaceRecognition from './components/FaceRecognition/FaceRecognition';
import Logo from './components/Logo/Logo';
import ImageLinkForm from './components/ImageLinkForm/ImageLinkForm';
import Rank from './components/Rank/Rank';

const returnClarifai = (imageUrl) => {
  // Your PAT (Personal Access Token) can be found in the portal under Authentication
  const PAT = '';
  // Specify the correct user_id/app_id pairings
  // Since you're making inferences outside your app's scope
  const USER_ID = '';    
  const APP_ID = '';
  // Change these to whatever model and image input you want to use
  const MODEL_ID = 'face-detection';
  const IMAGE_URL = imageUrl;

  const raw = JSON.stringify({
    "user_app_id": {
        "user_id": USER_ID,
        "app_id": APP_ID
    },
    "inputs": [
        {
            "data": {
                "image": {
                    "url": IMAGE_URL
                }
            }
        }
    ]
  });

const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Key ' + PAT
    },
    body: raw
  };

return requestOptions
}

const initialState = {
  input: '',
  imageUrl: '',
  box: {},
  route: 'signin',
  isSignedIn: false,
  user: {
    id:'',
    name: '',
    email: '',
    entries: 0,
    joined: ''
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = initialState;
}

loadUser = (data) => {
  this.setState({user: {
    id: data.id,
    name: data.name,
    email: data.email,
    entries: data.entries,
    joined: data.joined
  }})
}

calculateFaceLocation = (data) => {
  const clarifaiFace = data.outputs[0].data.regions[0].region_info.bounding_box;
  const image = document.getElementById('inputImage');
  const width = Number(image.width);
  const height = Number(image.height);
  console.log(width, height);
    return {
      leftCol: clarifaiFace.left_col * width,
      topRow: clarifaiFace.top_row * height,
      rightCol: width - (clarifaiFace.right_col * width),
      bottomRow: height - (clarifaiFace.bottom_row * height)
    }
  } 

  displayFaceBox = (box) => {
    this.setState({box: box});
  }

  onInputChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({input: event.target.value});
  }

  onSubmit = () => {
    this.setState({imageUrl: this.state.input});
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/imageurl', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          input: this.state.input
        })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
        const requestOptions = returnClarifai(this.state.input);

        fetch("https://api.clarifai.com/v2/models/" + 'face-detection' + "/outputs", requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            if (response) {
                fetch('http://localhost:3000/image', {
                    method: 'put',
                    headers: {
                      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        id: this.state.user.id
                    })
                })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(count => {
                    this.setState(Object.assign(this.state.user, {entries: count}))
                })
                .catch(console.log)
            }
            this.displayFaceBox(this.calculateFaceLocation(response))
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

  onRouteChange = (route) => {
    if (route === 'signout') {
      this.setState(initialState)
    } else if (route === 'home') {
      this.setState({isSignedIn: true})
    }
    this.setState({route: route});
  }

  render() {
    const { isSignedIn, imageUrl, route, box } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ParticlesBg type="circle" bg={true} />
        <Navigation isSignedIn={isSignedIn} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} />
        { route === 'home' 
          ? <div>
              <Logo />
              <Rank 
                name={this.state.user.name} 
                entries={this.state.user.entries}
              />
              <ImageLinkForm 
                onInputChange={this.onInputChange} 
                onButtonSubmit={this.onButtonSubmit}
              />
              <FaceRecognition box={box} imageUrl={imageUrl} />
            </div>
          : (
            route === 'signin'
            ? <Signin loadUser={this.loadUser} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange}/>
            : <Register loadUser={this.loadUser} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange}/>
            )
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

server.js:
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
const cors = require('cors');
const knex = require('knex');
const { createClient } = require('@supabase/supabase-js');

const register = require('./controllers/register');
const signin = require('./controllers/signin');
const profile = require('./controllers/profile');
const image = require('./controllers/image');

const supabaseUrl = '';
const supabaseKey = ''; // Replace with your Supabase public key

const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseKey);

const db = knex({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
        host: '',
        user: '',
        password: '',
        database: '',
    }
});

const app = express();

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

app.get('/', (req, res)=> { res.send(db.users) })
app.post('/signin', signin.handleSignin(db, bcrypt))
app.post('/register', (req, res) => { register.handleRegister(req, res, db, bcrypt) })
app.get('/profile/:id', (req, res) => { profile.handleProfileGet(req, res, db)})
app.put('/image', (req, res) => { image.handleImage(req, res, db)})
app.post('/imageurl', (req, res) => { image.handleApiCall(req, res)})

app.listen(3000, ()=> {
    console.log('app is running on port 3000');
})

I've tried making the requests in Postman but I just get "Cannot POST /signin"
